# User can't select SVG in Episerver CMS (other image types are supported)

Tags: episerver

I am unable to get SVG images to show up in the "Select Image" box when a CMS user clicks the ellipse button for an image property on a page or block in Episerver. (Episerver 10.10.5.0)

The SVG images upload just fine, and they appear in the Assets Pane with the other images that have been uploaded. But when the user tries to select an image, only the other image types that are in the same folder appear.

I tried adding support via the model (Models\Media\VectorImageFile.cs) as suggested in the [blog post here](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Ben-McKernan/Dates/2015/7/supporting-svg-images/). When that didn't work, I removed VectorImageFile.cs and tried adding "svg" to the list of image extensions in Models\Media\ImageFile.cs:

```
[ContentType(DisplayName = "ImageFile", GUID = "88284fbf-9d34-469b-a259-716f8aac5529", Description = "")]
[MediaDescriptor(ExtensionString = "jpg,jpeg,jpe,ico,gif,bmp,png,svg")]
```

Both of those attempts compiled without issue, but did not make SVG images available to the user when selecting an image file for an image property of a page or block.

Hope I've provided enough information. I'm an Episerver noob (and a C# noob, tbh). Any guidance will be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Is it that episerver does not show preview of svg image (that is expected)? Or do you mean you cannot actually see any of the svg images in list when browse for image? What will happen if you try drag & drop SVG image from media Tab - will it work? You can try adding `[AllowedTypes(typeof(...))]` with providing your custom type for image in it

Comment: Thanks Lanorkin -- it's when I browse for an image that the svg images don't appear, only the other types. Actually, it's also not showing a preview. So, both. When I try to drag & drop the SVG from the assets pane, it drags successfully but says, "The 'GenericMedia' can not be displayed".

Comment: Here's [another apparently elegant solution](https://www.luminary.com/blog/image-metadata-svg-thumbnails-episerver-dxc), but once again I simply don't know _where_ to put this code he's suggesting.

Comment: I think it is possible that the steps you describe here actually did solve the problem. The confusing thing is that *the fix does not affect files that have already been uploaded*. Overwriting files also does not help. All SVG media items that are unavailable for selection in image properties have to be deleted (trashed) and freshly uploaded after the fix has been applied. Hovering over an item in a media file list displays the media type. Assuming the second solution (adding svg to the extensions for ImageFile), freshly uploaded files should show "ImageFile" upon hover.

Comment: Otto--thanks so much for this comment! I will investigate this as soon as I have opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here are the answers I found to my question.

- Put [this code](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Ben-McKernan/Dates/2015/7/supporting-svg-images/) in a separate file, and make sure it's properly
  referenced/included in the project.
- Once it's there, you'll have a defined "VectorImageFile" type, but 1) users won't be able to upload SVG files anymore and 2) users still won't be able to select SVG images from a block editor with the UIHint.Image property set.
- [These guys](http://mariajemaria.net/another-failed-svg-upload) documented issue/annoyance #1 above. Change the inheritance of "VectorImageFile" from ImageData to MediaData. Now users can upload SVG images again. But they still can't select them.
- So, remove UIHint.Image from the property, allowing users to select whatever media or content type they want. Then, grab the ContentURL from the ContentReference, assign it to a string variable, and call that string variable as the src of an img tag in the View.

What. A. Pain.