# Episerver: which directive/namespace am I missing (to resolve error CS0246)? ("using ______;")

Tags: c#, episerver

Needing to support CMS-user uploaded SVG images in Episerver 10.10.5.0. It was a [schlep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62041700/user-cant-select-svg-in-episerver-cms-other-image-types-are-supported), but I was able to come right using [Marija's solution](http://mariajemaria.net/another-failed-svg-upload) (in which she documents several others having these issues...).

My difficulty now is with implementing the second bit of [Marija's solution](http://mariajemaria.net/another-failed-svg-upload), in which thumbnails are made available (rather than default icons) for the SVG images and in which the SVG images render properly in the editor:

```
    [ServiceConfiguration(typeof(IModelTransform), Lifecycle = ServiceInstanceScope.Singleton)]
public class ThumbnailModelTransform : StructureStoreModelTransform
{
    public ThumbnailModelTransform(
        IContentProviderManager contentProviderManager,
        ILanguageBranchRepository languageBranchRepository,
        IContentLanguageSettingsHandler contentLanguageSettingsHandler,
        ISiteDefinitionRepository siteDefinitionRepository,
        IEnumerable hasChildrenEvaluators,
        LanguageResolver languageResolver, UrlResolver urlResolver, TemplateResolver templateResolver) :
    base(
        contentProviderManager,
        languageBranchRepository,
        contentLanguageSettingsHandler, siteDefinitionRepository,
        hasChildrenEvaluators,
        languageResolver,
        urlResolver,
        templateResolver)
    {
    }
    public override void TransformInstance(IContent source, StructureStoreContentDataModel target, IModelTransformContext context)
    {
        base.TransformInstance(source, target, context);
        var contentWithThumbnail = source as VectorFile;
        if (contentWithThumbnail != null)
        {
            var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance();
            var defaultUrl = urlResolver.GetUrl(contentWithThumbnail.ContentLink, null, new VirtualPathArguments { ContextMode = ContextMode.Default });
            target.ThumbnailUrl = defaultUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the dreaded **error CS0246** for most of the terms in Marija's code (one example below):

```
The type or namespace name 'StructureStoreModelTransform' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Here are the terms for which I receive that error (or a similar one):

```
StructureStoreModelTransform
ServiceConfiguration
IModelTransform
Lifecycle
StructureStoreContentDataModel
IModelTransformContext
ISiteDefinitionRepository
IEnumerable
LanguageResolver
UrlResolver
TemplateResolver
```

I've tried adding a bunch of directives: (or dependencies? what are these called?)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
```

...and a laundry list of others that didn't work, which I won't include here.

My colleague's installation of VS community autofills in these 'using' statements once VS determines they're needed. Mine (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview, Version 16.7.0 Preview 2.0) is not so kind.

So, two questions I guess, but one or the other will likely sort me out:

1. Where on earth are these EPiServer namespaces documented??? For
   real; I've worn Google out searching.
2. Alternatively, how can I get
   my Visual Studio to kindly fill in the gaps, like my colleague's
   does?

Thanks for any assistance. Banging my head against the wall here.

Comment: That specific type is located in the `EPiServer.Cms.Shell.UI.Rest.Models.Transforms.Internal` namespace, so use with care. :) The class itself is `public`, but the "Internal" suffix on the namespace indicates Episerver may change the implementation and introduce breaking changes without notice.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks!  `EPiServer.Cms.Shell.UI.Rest.Models.Transforms.Internal` takes care of the top one on my list, `StructureStoreModelTransform`. But none of the rest. How did you know which namespace that one is located in? Is it documented somewhere? Because then I could look it up rather than asking on forums like this one! :-)

Comment: Internal classes aren't documented, but reflection (e.g. Dotpeek) works well - if you know where to look... :/ The `EPiServer` and `EPiServer.Framework` assemblies are good places to start. Dotpeek allows you to easily locate a type within a reflected assembly.

Comment: Thanks. I've downloaded it and I'm giving it a go.